# How do I append python code, scraped from wikipedia, in the best way

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, append

*Need help with getting the code into a csv file.*

So I have my code, but I dont know the best way of making it into a csv file. I have tried to do data.append. But since the code is how it is, It only takes part of the code and not all. How do I get it all next to eachother?
I want it like this:

```
Title, Year

Bla, 2000
```

But this is how it appears when I try it:

```
bla,

bla, 

, 2000

, 2000
```

This is my entire code:

```
import requests
import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import re
from datetime import timedelta
import datetime
import time


#the websites
urls = ['https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transistor_count']
data =[]

#getting the websites and the data
for url in urls:   
    my_url = requests.get(url) 
    html = my_url.content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')

    ts = time.time()
    st = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(ts).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') 


    My_table = soup.find('table',{'class':'wikitable sortable'})
    links = My_table.findAll('tr')
    number = My_table.findAll('td')
    numbers = number[0::1]
    numberss = numbers[0::2]
    numbersss = numberss[0::1]
    numbering = numbersss[1::3]
    for num in numbering:
        nums = num.text
        print(nums)
        if nums.startswith("Apple A9X"):
            break        

    My_table2 = soup.find('table',{'class':'wikitable sortable'})
    links2 = My_table2.findAll('tr')
    number2 = My_table2.findAll('td')
    numbers2 = number2[0::1]
    numberss2 = numbers2[0::2]
    numbering2 = numberss2[2::3]
    for num2 in numbering2:
        nums2 = num2.text
        if nums2.startswith("2015") or nums2.startswith("2016") or nums2.startswith("2017") or nums2.startswith("2018") or nums2.startswith("2019"):
            print(nums2) 

            data.append({'Year':nums2})

    for link in links:
        My_row = link.find('td')
        if My_row == None:
            print(None)
        else:
            My_rows = My_row.text
            print(My_rows)

            data.append({
                'Title':My_rows})



    My_second_table = My_table.find_next_sibling('table')  
    links2 = My_second_table.findAll('tr')
    for linka in links2:
        My_new_row = linka.find('td')
        if My_new_row == None:
            print(None)
        else:
            My_new_rows = My_new_row.text
            print(My_new_rows)

            data.append({
                'Title':My_new_rows
            })


with open('data.csv', 'w',encoding='UTF-8', newline='') as f:
    fields = ['Title', 'Year']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=fields)
    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerows(data)
testing = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
heading = testing.head()
discription = testing.describe()
#print(heading)
```

I might have done this in a hard way =P so if you have any solutions on how to make it simplified I would appreciate it, however, I am just looking for a  way to get it to a csv file.

Thank you!

Comment: Use `'a'` to append instead of `'w'`.

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: I wanna do, data.append({'Title': name, 'Year':name}) and it looking normal. I only now get loops or like I said in the beginning, one after another.

Comment: Are you expecting `MP944 (20-bit, 6-chip), 1970` in df?

Comment: @shaikmoeed, yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `BeautifulSoup`, in the way you did but with some changes

Try below code,

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv


#the websites
urls = ['https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transistor_count']
data =[]

#getting the websites and the data
for url in urls:   
##    my_url = requests.get(url)
    my_url = urllib.request.urlopen(url)

    html = my_url.read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')

    my_table = soup.find('table',{'class':'wikitable sortable'})

    with open('data.csv', 'w',encoding='UTF-8', newline='') as f:
        fields = ['Title', 'Year']
        writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=',')
        writer.writerow(fields)

    with open('data.csv', "a", encoding='UTF-8') as csv_file:
        writer = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter=',')    
        for tr in my_table.find_all('tr')[2:]: # [2:] is to skip empty and header 
            tds = tr.find_all('td')
            try:
                title = tds[0].text.replace('\n','')
            except:
                title = ""
            try:
                year = tds[2].text.replace('\n','')
            except:
                year = ""

            writer.writerow([title, year])
```

Comment: gives the error: UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u03bc' in position 4: character maps to <undefined>

Comment: Omg! It works, thanks, there is only one tiny problem. It breaks half way because of the table on wikipedia. How would one go around that?

Answer (score 1):

Use `pandas` library

- [`pd.read_html()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.read_html.html) - Read HTML tables into a list of DataFrame objects.
- [`DataFrame.to_csv()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) - Write object to a comma-separated values (csv) file.

**Ex.**

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_html("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transistor_count")[0]
# save datafrmae into csv file
data.to_csv("transistor_count.csv")
print(data)
```

**O/P:**

```
                    Processor Transistor count          Date of introduction            Designer   MOS process    Area
0      MP944 (20-bit, 6-chip)              NaN  1970[14] (declassified 1998)  Garrett AiResearch           NaN     NaN
1  Intel 4004 (4-bit, 16-pin)             2250                          1971               Intel     10,000 nm  12 mm²
2  Intel 8008 (8-bit, 18-pin)             3500                          1972               Intel     10,000 nm  14 mm²
3  NEC μCOM-4 (4-bit, 42-pin)    2,500[17][18]                          1973                 NEC  7,500 nm[19]       ?
4    Toshiba TLCS-12 (12-bit)  over 11,000[20]                          1973             Toshiba      6,000 nm  32 mm²
....
....
```

Filter dataframe column

```
col = ['Processor','Date of introduction']
print(data[col])
                    Processor          Date of introduction
0      MP944 (20-bit, 6-chip)  1970[14] (declassified 1998)
1  Intel 4004 (4-bit, 16-pin)                          1971
2  Intel 8008 (8-bit, 18-pin)                          1972
3  NEC μCOM-4 (4-bit, 42-pin)                          1973
4    Toshiba TLCS-12 (12-bit)                          1973
```

Comment: I kind of need to use beautiful soup though. But this was very simple. How do I target processors to only display?

Comment: @Sofelia You are using beautifulsoup to scrape table data, save data into csv file and load data into pandas dataframe. As I see request web page data have into between table tag.  so try with pandas in-built method to scrape table data.

Comment: Sorry but I didnt understand that middle part " As I see request web page data have into between table tag."

And I know it is easier with pandas but I need to use beautifulsoup, so how do I do that?

Comment: @Sofelia It means your website data between HTML table tag like <table></table>, so you can scrape table data using pandas library.

Comment: So is there no way to do it the way I did it? :) I mean without using pandas?  And use beautiful soup up front?

Comment: @Sofelia You can use as well beautifulsoup, but in that case you have to manage all things manually, like table header with respective row data.

Comment: @Sofelia Than post your question on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/